# Can one of my cats find my missing cat?

Tags: cats, lost-pet

I have two cats now as the third cat ran away three days ago. I am wondering if I should let one of my other cats out, as they are very obedient, always come back, and stay within the vicinity of the house. Do you think that my other cat can find my missing cat?

My missing cat has been missing for three days. She is a very curious but easily scared cat. She snuck out while my mom was letting out the dogs about two nights ago. We have been doing the usual search for her by looking for her at night, leaving out food, and calling her name.

Answer (score 5):

I honestly don't see how this would work out.

Cats can live together, but they are not as social as dogs. If your missing cat saw one of your other cats, it *might* come to them, but it might as well come to you, if it saw or heard you. Your other cat, on the other hand, has no reason at all to go searching for the missing cat and leading it back home. That's stuff from Disney films, but not how reality works.

Maybe you're hoping that your cat would sniff out and track the missing one. But again, cats are no dogs. Some dog breeds were specifically bred to track prey for humans on a hunt. Cats don't accompany humans on hunts, and they don't track their own prey when hunting. They lay in wait, find rodents by their sounds and pounce on them to catch them. No need for tracking. Apart from that, after 3 days the scent is probably dissipated too much already.

And don't forget that in the worst case, you'd have 2 missing cats.

Comment: Thank you. Is our best optio just to wait it out? We put flyers and asked people in our neighborhood to check garages sheds and backyard. We put some food near where she was last time but it was not touched the last two days or any food we left out. It’s been a long 3 days

Answer (score 5):

When my cat was missing, a professional told me to check in hiding places very close to my house. He said cats don't usually go too far. He was right! I finally found him hiding on my neighbor's porch behind a plant.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest waiting a few more days and your problem might just solve itself because cats have a good sense of smell. But I doubt it will happen, especially if your cats used to fight each other, then the missing one might tend to run away. I recommend going on a walk around the neighbourhood and looking for signs of you cat's presence or asking neighbours.